# i have task to get in one query result of two selects merge by columns

Tags: mysql

First query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `test` t ,`user_test` ut,`user` u 
WHERE test_type_id = 1
AND t.created_on >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND t.created_on < CURDATE()
AND t.id = ut.test_id
AND u.id = ut.user_id
AND u.user_account_type_id != X 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'  
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'
```

Second query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 0, 1, 0)), 0) aaa, COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 1, 1, 0)), 0) bbb 
FROM transaction_test tt ,USER u
WHERE tt.created_on >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10000 DAY) AND tt.created_on < CURDATE()
AND u.id = tt.user_id
AND u.user_account_type_id != X
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'  
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'
```

Have to get result from one single select select 
I  try this

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 0, 1, 0)), 0) Email, COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 1, 1, 0)), 0) SMS ,(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `test` t ,`user_test` ut,`user` u 
WHERE test_type_id = 1
AND t.created_on >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND t.created_on < CURDATE()
AND t.id = ut.test_id
AND u.id = ut.user_id
AND u.user_account_type_id != X 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'  
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
)
FROM transaction_test tt ,USER u
WHERE tt.created_on >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10000 DAY) AND tt.created_on < CURDATE()
AND u.id = tt.user_id
AND u.user_account_type_id != X
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'  
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'
```

i am not rely happy with  using twice

```
AND u.user_account_type_id != X
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'  
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'
```

this part can any body advise how avoid this? thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you add transaction_test tt table to the first SELECT...JOIN part? It looked possible at a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try i have joined your both query because in queries you have the same conditions and i have used the `INNER JOIN` to sure that both tables have the data if your concerned to get data from the right table or left table change it accordingly to the `RIGHT JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ,COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 0, 1, 0)), 0) aaa, COALESCE(SUM(IF(tt.type = 1, 1, 0)), 0) bbb 
FROM `test` t ,
INNER JOIN `user_test` ut ON (t.id = ut.test_id)
INNER JOIN `user` u  ON (u.id = ut.user_id)
INNER JOIN `transaction_test` tt  ON (u.id = tt.user_id)
WHERE test_type_id = 1
AND t.created_on >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND t.created_on < CURDATE()
AND u.user_account_type_id != X 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' 
AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...' AND u.usr NOT LIKE '%...'
```

Hope it works fine